# Layer List Drawable - clip bitmap by nine-patch?

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable, nine-patch

I would like to create `Drawable` that contains `nine-patch` and a `Bitmap`.

I put them together in Layer List Drawable, but it turns out that `Bitmap` is extending `nine-patch` beyond the edge.

Is there any way to "cut" `Bitmap` so it won't be overlapping `nine-patch`?

EDIT: Actually it seems that I would like to shrink background to wrap content and ingore big bitmap in background.

Answer (score 0):

a nine patch by definition doesn't have a size.

From the sounds of things you haven't configured your nine patch correctly.

Please attach an image of what you're seeing and your source files.